# compiler warnings with Eigen Tensor example

Tags: c++, eigen3

I'm doing a little experimenting with the unsupported Eigen Tensor library. In the documentation, there's a little example showing how to resize a tensor object:

```
Tensor<float, 3> t_3d(2, 3, 4);
t_3d = Tensor<float, 3>(3, 4, 3);
```

When I compile a main() which basically consists of those two lines, I get a bunch of verbiage from the compiler:

```
In file included from /usr/local/include/eigen3/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/Tensor:88:0,
                 from tensor_test.cpp:6:
/usr/local/include/eigen3/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/src/Tensor/TensorEvaluator.h: In instantiation of ‘struct Eigen::TensorEvaluator<const Eigen::Tensor<float, 3>, Eigen::DefaultDevice>’:
/usr/local/include/eigen3/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/src/Tensor/TensorAssign.h:96:70:   required from ‘struct Eigen::TensorEvaluator<const Eigen::TensorAssignOp<Eigen::Tensor<float, 3>, const Eigen::Tensor<float, 3> >, Eigen::DefaultDevice>’
/usr/local/include/eigen3/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/src/Tensor/Tensor.h:406:14:   required from ‘Eigen::Tensor<Scalar_, NumIndices_, Options_, IndexType>& Eigen::Tensor<Scalar_, NumIndices_, Options_, IndexType>::operator=(const Eigen::Tensor<Scalar_, NumIndices_, Options_, IndexType>&) [with Scalar_ = float; int NumIndices_ = 3; int Options_ = 0; IndexType_ = long int]’
tensor_test.cpp:29:36:   required from here
/usr/local/include/eigen3/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/src/Tensor/TensorEvaluator.h:156:71: warning: ignoring attributes on template argument ‘Eigen::PacketType<float, Eigen::DefaultDevice>::type {aka __vector(4) float}’ [-Wignored-attributes]
     PacketAccess = (internal::unpacket_traits<PacketReturnType>::size > 1),
                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~
/usr/local/include/eigen3/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/src/Tensor/TensorEvaluator.h: In instantiation of ‘struct Eigen::TensorEvaluator<Eigen::Tensor<float, 3>, Eigen::DefaultDevice>’:
/usr/local/include/eigen3/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/src/Tensor/TensorAssign.h:100:65:   required from ‘struct Eigen::TensorEvaluator<const Eigen::TensorAssignOp<Eigen::Tensor<float, 3>, const Eigen::Tensor<float, 3> >, Eigen::DefaultDevice>’
/usr/local/include/eigen3/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/src/Tensor/Tensor.h:406:14:   required from ‘Eigen::Tensor<Scalar_, NumIndices_, Options_, IndexType>& Eigen::Tensor<Scalar_, NumIndices_, Options_, IndexType>::operator=(const Eigen::Tensor<Scalar_, NumIndices_, Options_, IndexType>&) [with Scalar_ = float; int NumIndices_ = 3; int Options_ = 0; IndexType_ = long int]’
tensor_test.cpp:29:36:   required from here
/usr/local/include/eigen3/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/src/Tensor/TensorEvaluator.h:42:71: warning: ignoring attributes on template argument ‘Eigen::PacketType<float, Eigen::DefaultDevice>::type {aka __vector(4) float}’ [-Wignored-attributes]
     PacketAccess = (internal::unpacket_traits<PacketReturnType>::size > 1),
                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~
In file included from /usr/local/include/eigen3/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/Tensor:121:0,
                 from tensor_test.cpp:6:
/usr/local/include/eigen3/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/src/Tensor/TensorExecutor.h: In instantiation of ‘static void Eigen::internal::TensorExecutor<Expression, Eigen::DefaultDevice, true>::run(const Expression&, const Eigen::DefaultDevice&) [with Expression = const Eigen::TensorAssignOp<Eigen::Tensor<float, 3>, const Eigen::Tensor<float, 3> >]’:
/usr/local/include/eigen3/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/src/Tensor/Tensor.h:407:65:   required from ‘Eigen::Tensor<Scalar_, NumIndices_, Options_, IndexType>& Eigen::Tensor<Scalar_, NumIndices_, Options_, IndexType>::operator=(const Eigen::Tensor<Scalar_, NumIndices_, Options_, IndexType>&) [with Scalar_ = float; int NumIndices_ = 3; int Options_ = 0; IndexType_ = long int]’
tensor_test.cpp:29:36:   required from here
/usr/local/include/eigen3/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/src/Tensor/TensorExecutor.h:61:17: warning: ignoring attributes on template argument ‘Eigen::TensorEvaluator<const Eigen::TensorAssignOp<Eigen::Tensor<float, 3>, const Eigen::Tensor<float, 3> >, Eigen::DefaultDevice>::PacketReturnType {aka __vector(4) float}’ [-Wignored-attributes]
       const int PacketSize = unpacket_traits<typename TensorEvaluator<Expression, DefaultDevice>::PacketReturnType>::size;
```

I can add a little code that populates the tensor, and then prints out the contents, and everything behaves as expected:

```
for (auto ii = 0; ii < 3; ii++) {
    for (auto jj = 0; jj < 4; jj++) {
        for (auto kk = 0; kk < 3; kk++) {
            t_3d(kk, jj, ii) = val++;
        }
    }
}
for (auto ii = 0; ii < 3; ii++) {
    for (auto jj = 0; jj < 4; jj++) {
        for (auto kk = 0; kk < 3; kk++) {
            std::cout << t_3d(kk, jj, ii) << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm wondering if anyone is familiar with the warnings issued, and how to address them?

Comment: I gave up silencing eigen's warning a long time ago. It warms a lot. As long as it is still doing what you want, ignore it.

Comment: @Jeffrey I may yet do that. I've also found boost to be a rich source of unwieldy compiler messages...

Comment: Are you on the most recent development version of Eigen? If you are and you experience these warnings file a bug report (also say what compiler and compilation flags you are using). If you don't care about fixing the warnings, include Eigen via `-isystem` instead of `-I` (if you use g++ or clang++).

Comment: Can't reproduce with any clang or gcc version I have. What Eigen version are you using? What compilation flags?

Comment: I'm using Eigen 3.3.1, and gcc 7.3.0. I've also tried Eigen 3.3.5 and 3.3.7 and got the same messages. Compilation flags:  -g -I/usr/local/include/eigen3 -std=c++14

Comment: I can reproduce with Eigen 3.3.7, but I really suggest to use the development branch if you want to use the Tensor module. `unsupported` modules are barely maintained in the stable branch.

Comment: @chtz Thanks for the advice - I'll give the development branch a try.

Comment: I grafted a few changes which will fix several warnings on the 3.3 branch (which will be part of the next 3.3.x release). But I would still suggest using the "default" branch. Some changes are a bit more complicated to back-port (and not really worth the effort).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to turn-off the warnings coming from `unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/src/Tensor` using `-isystem` option of g++.

I am using `gcc version 7.4.0` and `Eigen version 3.3.7 (323c052e1731)`